# How to make a function that includes a for loop non-blocking?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to make the below code asynchronous:

```
import asyncio
import random

async def count():
    l = []
    for i in range(10000000):
        l.append(i)
    return random.choice(l)

async def long_task1():
    print('Starting task 1...')
    task_output = await count()
    print('Task 1 output is {}'.format(task_output ))


async def long_task2():
    print('Starting task 2...')
    task_output = await count()
    print('Task 2 output is {}'.format(task_output ))

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(long_task1(), long_task2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Currently it will work synchronously.

Is it because the `count` function is lacking `await` statement?

I have tried reworking the function to include `await`:

```
async def count():
    l = []
    for i in range(10000000):
        l.append(i)
    choice = await random.choice(l)
    return choice
```

and it will start asynchronously (both `Starting task 1...` and `Starting task 2...` will get printed one after another), but then I get an error:

> TypeError: object int can't be used in 'await' expression

I understand that the error happened because the result of `random.choice(l)` is not an awaitable (a coroutine), but I don't know how to fix this without running in circles. Do I need to somehow refactor the for loop into a couroutine on its own?

Comment: I assume the loop in `count` is just an example and not your actual code ?

Comment: Well, this is an exercise I wrote for myself to get a grasp of asyncio. So actual code I guess:  a simulation of a long running task.

Comment: @I Funball: yes, but I don't want the `asyncio.sleep` in my code, I want the for loop. The `asyncio.sleep` works because it is an awaitable. I am looking for a way to turn the for loop into an awaitable.

Comment: @barciewicz I didn't see that specification in the question. I will try to find a different solution then. But you want the same output that would occur with a sleep?

Comment: @barciewicz see my edits. I added a way to not change your `count()` function at all as well as the way to refactor the for loop into a coroutine.

Comment: @barciewicz `await asyncio.sleep(0)` [**is**](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284) the way to turn a `for` loop (or any long-running code in an `async def`) into an awaitable that actually suspends. If you never suspend, you're not giving asyncio a chance to do its job. Normal asyncio code tends to be network-oriented, so it never has a need to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it because the count function is lacking `await` statement?

In short, yes, you have identified the issue correctly. To get parallel execution of tasks, you need not only to specify `async def`, but also to await something that suspends execution, thus returning control to the event loop. In asyncio that is typically the kind of call that would block a synchronous program, such as a sleep or a read from a socket that is not yet ready for reading.

To force a [temporary suspension](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284), you can add `await asyncio.sleep(0)` inside the loop in `count`. Adding `await` in front of an ordinary function such as `random.choice`, doesn't work because `await` requires an object that implements the awaitable interface, and in your code `random.choice` just returns an integer.

Comment: Good answer, he explicitly said without using sleep() however. But the overall point is useful.

Comment: @IFunball I didn't see that, but still, `sleep(0)` is kind of special in that it doesn't actually sleep, it just yields control to the event loop. See e.g. this old [github issue](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284) or this [doc issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue34476). If the code doesn't relinquish control to the event loop anywhere, one must either execute it with `run_in_executor` or insert explicit (fake) yield points, there's no way around that.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think it is the best solution. I only say it because I used sleep in my original solution and then he said he didn't want sleep. It's one of the comments under the original post.

Comment: @user4815162342: Thanks a lot! Still, two questions: 1. Putting `await asyncio.sleep(0)` inside the for loop makes the code running a lot longer than the original synchronous one, because - I guess - the control is yielded back to the controller on every iteration of the loop. Is this correct? 2. If `await requires an object that implements the awaitable interface, and in your code random.choice just returns an integer`, then why do the examples from this page: https://realpython.com/async-io-python/ utilizing `i = await randint(0, 10)` work?

Comment: @barciewicz Yes, you will need to restructure your code to yield less often, or switch to a non-async function executed using [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). Since your code is not solving a concrete problem, one cannot tell what would be the better approach.

Comment: Regarding the second question, the linked code runs because it defines an `async def randint` - but that accomplishes nothing, since there is no `await` inside of it. If you look carefully, you will notice that its callers are always awaiting something in addition to `randint()`, such as `asyncio.sleep()` or `randsleep()`. Without it the author would face the same problem your code is facing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls a `gather` that runs both `long_task1` and `long_task2` concurrently. Then you call an await on `count` in each function. But this will  `await` on that subroutine to finish. So the overall subroutine will still finish before the next subroutine begins. You need a function to suspend the entire task. I created two ways to circumvent this. Both involve creating new tasks.

Creating a new subroutine:

```
async def count():
   l = []
   await asyncio.wait_for(loopProcess(l), timeout=1000000.0)
   return random.choice(l)

async def loopProcess(l):
   for i in range(10000000):
      l.append(i)
```

You could also keep your `count` function the same as the original code and change your `long_task(1/2)` like this to make `count()` a new task:

```
async def long_task1():
   print('Starting task 1...')
   task_output = await asyncio.shield(count())
   print('Task 1 output is {}'.format(task_output ))


async def long_task2():
   print('Starting task 2...')
   task_output = await asyncio.shield(count())
   print('Task 2 output is {}'.format(task_output ))
```

You can also use `create_task` if you have python 3.7.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Answer (score 1):

For asyncio to work properly, you should not have any cpu intensive task (tight big for loop) in the event loop. As there is no way to get out of the for loop. If you use an explicit `asyncio.sleep` inside the loop, you are just going in and out of the coroutine unnecessarily and slowing the entire thing. If your goal is just to see how asyncio works, it is fine.

But in real world, if you have a cpu intensive task, you have two options

1. Use multiprocessing and delegate the task to a different process.
2. Use a native code binding that releases GIL and uses threads.

As the name suggests, the library is for asynchronous io. `async"io"`